# Why are my paths absolute after ob_get_contents in PHP?

Tags: php, absolute, ob-get-contents

For saving the executed contents of a php-File in a variable, I do the following:

```
ob_start();
include '/templates/post.php';
$html = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
return $html;
```

which works nice.

However, in the included "post.php", I have relative links to ressources like images.
Why on earth are they absolute, full qualified links on my localhost and also on the server? Locally, they look like:

```
http://localhost/myProjectname/img/img1.png
```

which is weird because in post.php, there's written:

```
<img src="/img/img1.png">
```

which is also an absolute, but not full qualified path to the file and I can't find any other reason apart from ob_get_contents. Am I missing something? Thanks!

Comment: output buffering wont change the contents of the buffer. you have some other code that is causing this.

Comment: How are you checking this? Is it in developer tools? If so, you might be looking at the `Full URL` text in the inspector.

Comment: Using `/img/img1.png` is not an absolute path. it is a relative path. when you use relative paths, the page reads them, changes them to absolute, and loads them based on the relative path. so your `/img/img1.png` is pulling `http://localhost/img/img1.png`

Comment: @Orangepill I already thought so, but can't find anything!

Comment: @Joe firebug, also sourcecode, both have the full URL in it

Comment: by sourcecode you mean when you view the source from the browser, not looking at it through some developer tool, a lot of the tools actually will expand your paths to urls

Comment: yes - but to be honest, I solved the problem, I don't remember what was the fault but it's working now. Too hot in switzerland to work. Thanks guys